# multicast on windows 10

Tags: windows, multicast

I have implemented an app in Android which communicates with another Windows app using multicast.

It is working properly on most Windows 10 machines, but on some others the app won't receive multicast packets.

I have firewall disabled to test. The router config seems not to be the issue since it works on most pcs.

**EDIT:**

I have run Wireshark on these pcs and multicast packets are not being received.

I have added a select for the network interface to use in the pc, and detected that the problem doesn't happen in all interfaces, some work and receive the packets, and some not

Comment: Run a packet capture on a problem machine and analyze the captured traffic.

Comment: If the devices are on a different network, you must enable multicast routing on the router. Multicast routing is very different than unicast routing. If they are on the same network, but on different switches, you could have a problem with IGMP snooping, and would need an mcast router or querier configured.